# Javascript | Generate number

Tags: javascript

I'm About writing a JavaScript code that generate an array `allColumns` contain a specific number of others arrays,

the inside arrays contain a specific numbers of INT selected randomly;

**The problem**

This Code generate duplicated arrays , i don't know why! any help ?

```js
function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


get_random = function (list) {
    return list[Math.floor((Math.random() * list.length))];
}



function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
let columnLenght = 3;
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let tableColumns = 3;
    let allColumns = [];
    let prevNumber = [];

    let prevResult = 0;

    while (j < tableColumns) {
        while (i < columnLenght) {

            if (prevNumber === undefined || prevNumber.length == 0) {
                let randomNumber = get_random([1, 2, 3, 4], i);
                $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

            } else {

                prevResult = prevNumber.reduce(getSum);
                if (prevResult == 0) {
                    let randomNumber = get_random([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
                    $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                    prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

                }
                if (prevResult == 1) {
                    let randomNumber = get_random([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]);
                    $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                    prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

                }
                if (prevResult == 2) {
                    let randomNumber = get_random([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]);
                    $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                    prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

                }
                if (prevResult == 3) {
                    let randomNumber = get_random([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1]);
                    $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                    prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

                }
                if (prevResult == 4) {
                    let randomNumber = get_random([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0]);
                    $('.testcontent').append('<h6 class="row">' + randomNumber + '</h6>');
                    prevNumber.push(randomNumber);

                }
            }
            i++;

        }
        console.log(prevNumber);
        allColumns.push(prevNumber);
        j++;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `INT` data type. All numbers are double-precision floating point numbers.

Comment: You're getting random numbers; why wouldn't there be a possibility of duplicates?

Comment: `columnLenght` <-- spelling mistake

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for the information :) i'm newbie and i learn from the internet and stackoverflow ,

Comment: The [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript#For_complete_beginners) is the best place to learn. Stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can!

Comment: @HereticMonkey all the arrays generated is the same evrey time , same when i generate a 100 array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not reset the array on every new row. You keep just adding to the same array and keep appending it to the other array. So when you start a loop of a row, create a new array to push in.

```
while (j < tableColumns) {
  let prevNumber = []; // redefine your array on each row
  let i = 0  // reset i
  while (i < columnLength) { // <-- spelling error
    /* code */
  }
  allColumns.push(prevNumber);
  j++;
}
```

Not sure why you are not using for loops

```
for (let j=0; j < tableColumns; j++) {
  const prevNumber = []
  for (let i=0; i < columnLength; i++) {
    /* code */
  }
  allColumns.push(prevNumber);
}
```

Comment: I Try that before i and try it now , the result Now ( the first arrow ) is correct, all next arrays are empty

Comment: Well you also do not reset i.... would make so much more sense to use for loops here.

Comment: Thank u , the problem is `sloved` ; i reset the `prevNumber` and i before the first `while`. but i don't get the difference

Comment: because you set it outside.... how is it supposed to know to go back to zero. It goes 0,1,2,3  and than next j loop goes and i is at 4 so it will not loop since 4 > 3.